# Struggling with Oracle Function with parameter (Reference to uninitialized collection)

Tags: oracle, function, procedure

I can't find what is wrong here, finally I decided to ask here for help.

This is how I am invoking:

```
  DECLARE
   RESSULT VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
   V_TEST1 CARS_TABLE:=CARS_TABLE();
   idx pls_integer :=0;
   BEGIN 
   V_TEST1.EXTEND(2);
    IDX := V_TEST1.COUNT; -- here there is NO problem

  RESSULT:=MYFUNCTION(1, V_TEST1);
  END;
```

This is what I am invoking..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION MYFUNCTION(
  CAR_ID IN INTEGER,
  MYOUTTABLE OUT CARS_TABLE)
RETURN VARCHAR2
 IS
RESSULT VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
idx pls_integer :=0;
BEGIN
IDX := MYOUTTABLE.COUNT; - HERE IS PROBLEM.. but why - I pass initialized collection
RETURN 'return param';
END MYFUNCTION;


 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE carElement
IS
OBJECT
 (
  kind VARCHAR2(60),
    created DATE );
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CARS_TABLE
```

AS
      TABLE OF carElement;

1. 00000 -  "Reference to uninitialized collection"
   *Cause:    An element or member function of a nested table or varray
          was referenced (where an initialized collection is needed)
          without the collection having been initialized.
   *Action:   Initialize the collection with an appropriate constructor
          or whole-object assignment.

Answer (score 2):

"IDX := MYOUTTABLE.COUNT; - HERE IS PROBLEM.. but why - I pass initialized collection"

you're resetting the collection to NULL on the input to the function call as you've defined the parameter as `OUT` which automatically nulls out the parameter as it calls the function ([documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#BCFHBGBI)).

```
 MYOUTTABLE OUT CARS_TABLE
```

if you want to preserve the input, then you need to pass it as `IN` or if you want to preserve teh input and also manipulate the object in the function then use `IN OUT`.

eg note with the first call it shows its null if i use `out`:

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_test1 cars_table:=cars_table();
  3
  4    function myfunction(
  5      car_id in integer,
  6      myouttable  &mode cars_table)
  7    return varchar2
  8    is
  9      ressult varchar2(1000 char);
 10      idx pls_integer :=0;
 11    begin
 12      if (myouttable is null)
 13      then
 14        dbms_output.put_line('ARRAY IS NULL');
 15      else
 16        idx := myouttable.count;
 17      end if;
 18      return 'return param';
 19    end myfunction;
 20  begin
 21
 22    v_test1.extend(2);
 23    dbms_output.put_line(myfunction(1, v_test1));
 24
 25  end;
 26  /
Enter value for mode: OUT
old   6:     myouttable  &mode cars_table)
new   6:     myouttable  OUT cars_table)
ARRAY IS NULL
return param

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for mode: IN OUT
old   6:     myouttable  &mode cars_table)
new   6:     myouttable  IN OUT cars_table)
return param

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```